How to connect to my pump to water lawn
I have a submersible well that feeds my pond thru a 1 1/4 above ground PVC. Where we live, our city water (connected to our home) has the lowest pressure I've ever encountered. So much that I can't get enough to sufficiently water my lawn more that a 4 ft diameter at a time. I'm trying to connect off the 1 1/4 pipe to use the well for the lawn, but the pressure is so high, it blows off every connector/adapter. Admittedly, I'm connecting a basic garden hose, which I'm sure can't support the pressure. I'm convinced there's a way to use the well, but I'm at a loss for what to do. Can anyone offer advice? I have absolutely no knowledge of any of this, so (be kind) but explain it like I'm 5, please

It would be a good idea to test your well pressure and flow so you know what you're working with. But when your water supply is too high-pressure, you should use a Pressure-Reducing Valve (PRV). These come in various sizes and usually have adjustable output pressure, so you could reduce it to a "normal city supply pressure" around 60 psi, or high-pressure irrigation if your system (sprinklers, plumbing) can handle it at around 100 psi.
Add to that, 1 1/4" is pretty large for water supply; municipal supply in my area is 3/4" for most houses or 1" for very large houses with multiple taps expected to be in use at once. Industrial supplies I'm sure go much larger. But you could "tee" off the main 1 1/4" supply with a smaller size like 3/4" and test the pressure and flow from that smaller tee, and apply the PRV to just that; it should help minimize the impact to your pond's water flow and may reduce the size of PRV you need.

You could use a pressure valve to provide whatever pressure you want from the well pump to the sprinklers.  But you would have to look at how often the pump runs to fill the pond, and how often you would want it to feed the sprinklers.  If pumping to the sprinklers also fills the pond, will that overfill the pond?   Or, if you only pump to the sprinklers, will the pump function ok at the lower flow rate with back pressure?   The pump's documentation should help.
Another solution would be to feed the sprinklers from the pond with a new dedicated pump.   Those are not expensive (just to confirm, this is a residential lawn with residential sprinklers, right?).  The complication with this is you need electric power available at the pond for the new pump.
